# Как использовать нейросеть обученную на генераторах Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, генераторы

обучил модель keras на генераторах, теперь если делаю

```
model.predict_generator(test_generator)
```

то все работает отлично, но как мне теперь применить это к изображениям?
мне нужно либо правильно сконвертировать изображение в массив (3 цвета) и вызвать, представленный ниже пример не работает (изображение в openCv)

```
data = img.astype(float)/255
model.predict(data)
#ValueError('Error when checking input: expected vgg16_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)',)
```

Либо преобразовать открытое изображение в генератор, вот только как это сделать?

формирование генератора:

```
def Get_generator_data(dir,img_width, img_height, batch_size):
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)
    return train_generator
```

Создание модели

```
def create_model(outNeron, size):


    # Загружаем предварительно обученную нейронную сеть VGG16
    vgg16_net = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, 
                      input_shape=(size, size, 3))

    # "Замораживаем" веса предварительно обученной нейронной сети VGG16
    vgg16_net.trainable = False

    # Создаем составную нейронную сеть на основе VGG16
    # Создаем последовательную модель Keras
    model = Sequential()
    # Добавляем в модель сеть VGG16 вместо слоя
    model.add(vgg16_net)
    # Добавляем в модель новый классификатор
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(outNeron))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    return model
```

Обучение модели

```
def Train_Model (model, train_generator, nb_train_samples, batch_size, val_generator, nb_validation_samples):
        сheckpoint = ModelCheckpoint('save/mnist-dense.hdf5', 
            monitor='val_acc', 
            save_best_only=True)
    # Компилируем составную нейронную сеть
        model.compile(loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy,
            optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), 
            metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Обучаем модель с использованием генераторов
        model.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
            epochs=35,
            validation_data=val_generator,
            validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
            callbacks=[сheckpoint])
```

Принт модели print(model.summary())

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
vgg16 (Model)                (None, 1, 1, 512)         14714688
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 512)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               131328
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 1028
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 4)                 0
=================================================================
Total params: 14,847,044
Trainable params: 132,356
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: Добавил описание, надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Чему у вас равно `img_width` и `img_height` - 224?

Comment: размер изображений во всех случаях 32х32

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе вывод: `print(model.summary())`?

Comment: Добавил в конец вопроса

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, модель требует массив размером 32:32:4 (1028*4), но почему? Что за 4 параметр добавляет генератор к изображению? Прозрачность?

Comment: какое значение вы передаете в качестве параметра `size` при вызове `create_model(outNeron, size)` ?

Comment: 32 так как картинка квадратная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте прочитать все изображения в один 4D массив и "скормить" этот массив `model.predict()`.

```
from pathlib import Path
from skimage.transform import resize as sk_resize
from skimage.io import imread as sk_imread


def read_image(fn, img_width=32, img_height=32, channels=3,
               mode='reflect', anti_aliasing=True):
    return sk_resize(sk_imread(fn),
                     output_shape=(img_width, img_height, channels),
                     mode=mode, anti_aliasing=anti_aliasing)

def read_images(files, img_width=32, img_height=32, channels=3):
    return np.array([read_image(f, img_width, img_height, channels)
                     for f in files])

size=32
path = Path(r'C:\download')
imgs4D = read_images([str(f) for f in path.glob('*.jpg')],
                     size, size, 3)

predictions = model.predict(imgs4D)
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. Все работает, правда сделал немного по другому:  <br/>

    `opa = img.astype(float)/255  

   opa = np.array([opa])  

   abd = model.predict(opa)`