# Использование готовой Keras модели нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Нейронная сеть по распознаванию изображений.

При использовании готовой, обученной h5 модели возникает такая ошибка:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:239 assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 40000)
```

Вот информация модели моей сети:

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)           (None, 200, 200, 16)      1216      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling (None, 100, 100, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_25 (Conv2D)           (None, 100, 100, 32)      12832     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_25 (MaxPooling (None, 50, 50, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_26 (Conv2D)           (None, 50, 50, 64)        51264     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_26 (MaxPooling (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_27 (Conv2D)           (None, 25, 25, 128)       204928    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_27 (MaxPooling (None, 12, 12, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 18432)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              18875392  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_12 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 256)               262400    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_13 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 771       
=================================================================
Total params: 19,408,803
Trainable params: 19,408,803
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Данные которые должны быть поданы на вход:
Изображение 200x200 px

Код подачи изображения:

```
img_path = '9.jpeg'
Image(img_path, width=200, height=200)
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(200, 200), color_mode = "grayscale")

x = image.img_to_array(img)

x = x.reshape(1, 40000)

x = 255 - x

x /= 255

prediction = model.predict(x)
```

Код создания модели:

```
# Создаем последовательную модель
model = Sequential()
# Сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding='same', 
                 input_shape=(200, 200, 3), activation='relu'))
# Слой подвыборки
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
# Слой подвыборки
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
# Слой подвыборки
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
# Слой подвыборки
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Полносвязная часть нейронной сети для классификации
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# Выходной слой, 131 нейрон по количеству классов
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax') )
```

Comment: Кажется, вы зря режим `grayscale` выбрали. Мне кажется, на входе ожидаются все цветовые компоненты. Не уверен, но можно проверить версию.

Comment: Могу поставить rgb, от этого ничего не меняется. Только что проверял.

Comment: А reshape(1, 40000) при этом не ругается? Странно, куда же он остальные цветовые компоненты девает.

Comment: В случае если я ставлю rgb, я выставляю 120000 соогтветственно (reshape(1, 120000)

Comment: Ну вот там требуется 4 измерения, а у вас 2 получается после такого решейпа

Comment: Могу ли я показать вам код обучения? Это поможет вам помочь мне?

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос код создания модели. Батчсайз  = 32.

Comment: `input_shape=(200, 200, 3)` - ну вот тут 3 измерения - ширина, высота, 3 цвета, ну и плюс будет 4-е измерение - это набор картинок. Вам надо сделать, чтобы `x` получился 4-мерным, а вы его делаете 2-мерным. Какая `shape` у `x` до `reshape`? Вам надо добавить в `x` дополнительное измерение (потому что у вас одна картинка, а на вход должна идти последовательность, пусть и из одной картинки), а не убить все остальные измерения. Где вы взяли именно такой код для `reshape`?

Comment: Вот пишут что-то такое скорее нужно использовать. Но не уверен только новое измерение должно быть в конце или в начале для нейросети: `image = image[..., np.newaxis]`

Comment: @NightLight, можете сделать [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919418/211923)

Comment: @CrazyElf , ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4 but received input with shape (None, 200, 200, 3)